# Create mongo backup/restore without indexes

Tags: mongodb

Im wondering how can I create a mongodump/mongorestore without backing up, restoring the indexes?

and how to incrementally restore a mongo db without restoring the indexes?

Comment: What is your goal as far as restoring without indexes? Also, this question belongs on DBA StackExchange but I assume it will be migrated :).

Comment: Im currently working on a project where 3 versions have being deployed but at least 60% of the indexes are not correctly set so we want to reindex the database, and also we want to move mongo from solaris to linux based servers, and currently the current index rebuild takes a long time, and since were remaking them, no need for them!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) utility creates a binary export of data from MongoDB and saves index definitions and collection options in a `metadata.json` associated with each database dumped. The index details do not take any significant space in your backup, and will normally be used by `mongorestore` to re-ensure indexes after each data for each collection is imported from a dump.

If you want to avoid creating any new secondary indexes after the restore completes, `mongorestore` has a [`--noIndexRestore` option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-noindexrestore).

Note: The [default `_id` index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index) is required, and always created.

> incrementally restore a mongo db without restoring the indexes?

The option for `--noIndexRestore` applies whether or not you are restoring into an existing database. If you `mongorestore` into an existing database with indexes using the `--noIndexRestore` option, no new index definitions will be added but existing indexes will still be updated as data is inserted.

Incremental backup & restore is really a separate question unless you have a simplistic use case: inserting new documents from successive dumps.

As at MongoDB 2.6, the `mongorestore` utility only inserts documents (i.e. there is no option for updates/upserts). You can use `mongorestore` to insert multiple dumps into an existing collection, but any documents causing duplicate key exceptions (eg. `_id`) will be skipped.

I would normally expect that an incremental backup & restore implies taking a delta of changes (all inserts/updates/deletions since a prior backup) and being able to re-apply those to an older copy of the same data. To achieve an incremental backup, you need a history of changes to data, which in MongoDB's case would be provided by the replica set [operation log (oplog)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/).

Comment: For archival use cases where you might want to add new documents/updates from dumps but never remove data, you might find it useful to watch/upvote [TOOLS-121: Add upsert option to MongoRestore](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-121) in the MongoDB issue tracker. Upserts via `mongorestore` are definitely a more specialised use case then doing a proper incremental backup/restore, and could result in divergence from the original database.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo mongorestore --db dbName ./dumpPath/  --noIndexRestore
```

Comment: Mind you explaining your solution please? Cheers!

Comment: this one is the short version of the previous answer.